# Postman Requests From Host Machine Are Not Able to Reach Tomcat Server Running On Docker Container

Tags: java, docker, rest, servlets, containers

I was working on a java servlet REST Api project [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/rajeshsinha1997/task-manager-rest-java), and I decided to create a Docker image for the project which I can deploy easily to some cloud platform or maybe publish to some container registry.

So I created the Dockerfile for the above mentioned requirement which has two stages in it.

At the first stage, it's pulling a maven docker image (**maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine**), and after copying the project source files it's building the project along with a .war file.

At the second stage, it's pulling a tomcat docker image (tomcat:10.1.19), and after copying the .war file generated in the first stage to the **webapps** forlder of tomcat, it's starting the tomcat server.

Below are the two commands I was using to build the docker image and run the generated docker container

`docker build -t tmr-app`

`docker run -it --rm -p 8080:8080 tmr-app`

I was expecting to receive a success response in postman when I was sending a valid POST request to the tomcat server running in the docker container. But in place I was receiving a 404 Error.

[image]

I tried removing the first stage of building the .war file in the container itself by copying the .war file generated in local to the **webapps** folder of the tomcat container. And surprisingly that time when I started the docker container from the updated docker image it was working as expected and I was getting a success response in postman also.

I'm new to docker and I'm kinda messed up with the multi-staged build process of docker. It will be great if someone can please help me with this issue.

Below is the Dockerfile I've created

```html
# get maven image
FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS maven

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/var/app

# copy project management file (POM.XML)
COPY pom.xml .

# copy source files
COPY src .

# build project
RUN ["mvn", "clean", "install"]

# get tomcat image
FROM tomcat:10.1.19 AS server

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

# copy war file into the tomcat webapps
COPY --from=maven /usr/var/app/target/*.war .

# expose port
EXPOSE 8080

# run tomcat server
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

And, below is the Dockerfile that worked!

```html
# get tomcat image
FROM tomcat:10.1.19

# set work directory
WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

# copy war file into the tomcat webapps
COPY target/*.war .

# expose port
EXPOSE 8080

# run tomcat server
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

Comment: Not a Java developer and so it would be challenging to repro your issue. However, I can provide some debugging guidance. When you build the images, you should receive build output that shows any errors that are produced during the container image build. That you can't access the page (404) is insufficient information. You know the app builds (#2 works) so, what step(s) in #1 behaved incorrectly? One way to debug this is to add logging steps to the `Dockerfile` e.g. after the `RUN mvn clean install` in #1, add a `RUN ls -la /usr/var/app/target/*.war`

Comment: Another way to debug this is to (manually) implement the steps from the `Dockerfile`, run the e.g. `maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine` image with the file `COPY` steps and manually effect the `RUN` steps to observe the behavior.

Comment: The .war file was generated correctly which I've checked, and even it was present in the webapps directory of the tomcat container after copying. 


Also I've verified that there was no error logged while I started the tomcat container.

Answer (score 0):

I attempted to but am **unable** to repro your issue.

I'm not a Java|Tomcat dev and so I've a slightly different `Containerfile` in which `mvn` is used to generate a basic app.

I wonder whether there's an artifact that you're not copying between your `maven` and `server` build steps in your multi-stage build that's present in the single-stage build (explaining why that one works)!?

`Containerfile.1`:

```
FROM maven:3.9.6-eclipse-temurin-17-alpine AS maven

# Because mvn generate creates 'app' folder
WORKDIR /usr/var

RUN mvn archetype:generate \
    -DgroupId=com.example \
    -DartifactId=app \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp \
    -DinteractiveMode=false

# Need to run mvn from within app folder (and it is not workdir)
RUN cd app && mvn clean install

# Debugging
RUN tree

FROM tomcat:10.1.19 AS server

WORKDIR /usr/local/tomcat/webapps

COPY --from=maven /usr/var/app/target/*.war .

# Debugging
RUN ls -la

# This is documentation only; no effect
EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I use `podman` but you can replace `podman` with `docker`:

```bash
Q="78097216"

podman build \
--tag=stackoverflow:${Q}-1 \
--file=./Containerfile.1 \
${PWD}
```

Yields:

```
[1/2] STEP 5/5: RUN tree
.
└── app
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── src
    │   └── main
    │       ├── resources
    │       └── webapp
    │           ├── WEB-INF
    │           │   └── web.xml
    │           └── index.jsp
    └── target
        ├── app
        │   ├── META-INF
        │   ├── WEB-INF
        │   │   ├── classes
        │   │   └── web.xml
        │   └── index.jsp
        ├── app.war
        ├── classes
        └── maven-archiver
            └── pom.properties
```

```
[2/2] STEP 4/6: RUN ls -la
total 4
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root   14 Mar  3 19:45 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 root root   14 Mar  3 19:45 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 1617 Mar  3 19:45 app.war
```

And then:

```bash
podman run \
--interactive --tty --rm \
--publish=8080:8080/tcp \
stackoverflow:${Q}-1
```

And

```
curl \
--location \
--silent \
http://localhost:8080/app \
--write-out '%{response_code}' \
--output /dev/null
```

Yields

```
200
```